# Catching program abort inside a defined exception class

Tags: c++, linux, exception, sigabrt

I am running a binary from inside of my c++ program.
I am trying to make some retry logic in case it fails before the program fails and main returns.
I am catching an exception class that i defined and based on it I execute the retry logic else I throw to main to terminate the program.

The code is working fine but I am having a problem when I press (ctrl+C) while the  other binary is running (when I abort the program).
It treats the exception as my defined exception and executes the try logic which is wrong since we want to abort the program and not retry.

How can I handle the abort case in this situation?

```
void run(){
    try{
       if(!runOtherBinary())
           throw binaryexception(message);
    }catch(binaryexception& e){
           someretrylogic();
    }catch(...){
           throw;
    }
}

int main(){
    try{
        run();
    }
    catch(binaryexception& e){

    }catch(...){

    } 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], I guess what is happening is that `runOtherBinary` is returning false when you interrupt your program (which program, this program or your other program?)?

Comment: Yes that is correct when I press ctrl+c while the other binary is running it will return false.
I wanted to know if there is a way to differentiate between aborting the program and other exceptions in order to handle the aborting case separately and make the program terminate and not retry.

Comment: Presumably you can make use of the return code of the process, still need a [mcve]